# Django : customizing FileField's current file in templates

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-file-upload

I am rendering a simple form with a file field.

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Review

        fields = [
            'file',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'file': forms.ClearableFileInput(),
        }
```

While rendering, the form shows `Current file - /xyz/xyz/xyz.pdf` besides the file input.

However, I do not allow direct access to the files. All requests goes through the analytics_logger function before loading the file.

So, I want to customise the `Current file` html from

`Current file - <a href="{0}">{1}</a>` to

`Current file - <a href="{% url 'analytics_logger' {0} %}">{1}</a>`

I also don't want to display the full path of the file. Only the filename should be displayed.

How can I do it in Django 3.x?

Answer (score 2):

Following steps are recommended in case of `CustomClearableFileInput()`.

1. Override the `template_name` variable of the `ClearableFileInput` class. A new class can be created in the same forms.py file.
2. 

```
class CustomClearableFileInput(ClearableFileInput):
  template_name = 'widgets/customclearablefileinput.html'
```

3. Create a new file `widgets/customclearablefileinput.html` in the templates directory.
4. Fill the `widgets/customclearablefileinput.html` file by modifing the [original code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html) of the widget template as per your requirement.
5. You can change the href tag in the `customclearablefileinput.html` to wrap the link in the analytics_logger.

   **`<a href="{% url 'analytics_logger' widget.attrs.analytics_logger_id %}">`**
   `{{ widget.value }}`
   `</a>`
6. Next you can pass variables as part of form attributes that can accessed to replace the native full filename and customise the url tag.

   `<a href="{% url 'analytics_logger' widget.attrs.analytics_logger_id %}">`
   **`{{ widget.attrs.filename }}`**
   `</a>`
7. Following steps are recommended to pass the variables. Pass the variables while initilizing the form in the views.py

   ```
   form = ReviewForm(instance= reviewform_instance, analytics_logger_id=reviewform_instance.pk, filename = reviewform_instance.filename)
   ```
8. Next, override the **init** method of the form and update the attributes of the field.

   ```
   self.fields['processed_book'].widget.attrs.update( {'analytics_logger_id': analytics_logger_id, 'filename': filename,})
   ```
9. Include the following in the settings.py

   `FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'`
10. Add `'django.forms'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.
11. Now, you can include the new overridden class in the widget.

    ```
    class Meta:
        model = Review

        fields = [
            'file',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'file': CustomClearableFileInput(),
        }
    ```